# iOS cell accessoryView set the same view stuck

Tags: ios, accessoryview

**The source code：**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (UITableView *)tableView
{
   if (!_tableView) {
       CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
       frame.size.height -= (64 + 40);
       _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame  style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
       _tableView.separatorColor = __color_ListSepatator;
       _tableView.dataSource = self;
       _tableView.delegate = self;
       _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
       _tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
       _tableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
   }
   return _tableView;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
   return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return 45.0f;
}
/*Here is dalegate*/
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *string_id = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:string_id];
   if (!cell) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:string_id];
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   }

   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];
   /*Here is jammed*/
   cell.accessoryView = self.viewccessory;
   return cell;
}
/*Here is propety*/
- (UIView *)viewccessory
{
   if (!_viewccessory) {
       _viewccessory = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)];
       _viewccessory.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
   }
   return _viewccessory;
}
```

**Question**

When different cell repeat the same accessoryView Settings, getting stuck when I was out of the controller, can't into the interface

Each time when the controller card dead don't know why.Why can't accessoryView set the same view?Ask everybody to help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`accessoryView` for each tableview cell should be independent but not shared, you should make a new view very time when assigning to table view cell.

Why `acessoryView` can't be shared? Each view should only has one superview.

Comment: I understand what you mean.Repeat Settings won't automatically select the last cell as the parent view?But why is stuck.The bottom layer of the handle is too unfriendly.The design logic should not be stuck at least